# AWS CodeBuild not generating correct artifact files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo with yarn workspaces and have the following structure

```
packages
  server
    ... @my-repo/server files
  shared
    translations
      ... @my-repo/translations files
    validations
      ... @my-repo/validations files
```

and I use `@my-repo/translations` and `@my-repo/validations` are dependencies of in `@my-repo/server`.

To build the server app, I use the following `buildspec.yml`

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 14
    commands:
      - echo Installing Yarn...
      - npm install -g yarn
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
      - yarn install
      - echo Building Shared Packages ...
      - yarn buildShared
      - echo Listing directories ...
      - ls node_modules/@my-repo/*
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
      - yarn install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - yarn workspace @my-repo/server build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  discard-paths: no
```

The `yarn buildShared` command is a command I created to build all packages that are in the shared folder (simply run `yarn workspace @my-repo/foo build` for all shared packages in one command)

And one of the steps is to print what is inside `node_modules/@my-repo` directory and this prints everything as expected (I'm expecting all of my packages to be inside and correctly build, generating a `dist` folder).

[image]

And this CodeBuild create a Build Artifact in S3, but when I download and open the latest created BuildArtifact, I don't see any folder `node_modules/@my-repo` but I see a `node_modules` folder with the "normal" (not from yarn workspace) packages.

After try everything I could, I decided to create a temporary directory with every package I need from `@my-repo` in a temporary folder that I would copy from that and put back in `node_modules` (I know this is wrong, but I only did this to debug what was happening).

So I added this to my `buildspec.yml`

```
  - cp -r node_modules/@happyr-health/ ./temp_modules
  - ls
```

And apparently It worked, because the `ls` listed the `temp_modules` folder, but again, when downloading the latest build from S3, there was no `temp_modules`.

I can't figure out why some files are generated in the artifact and others aren't.

This is the second full day I'm trying to figure out "Why aren't the files from `node_modules` are correctly generated in the S3 bucket?"